# Started Kaggle Problem : Microsoft Malware Classification IN GCP

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, malware-detection

Steps:

> Created account in GCP
>   configured everything
>   While trying to launch Jupyter notebook in GCP after connecting through SSH and pasting the IP in browser followed by port - getting error , means i am not able to load url - PLEASE HELP
>   how to start with Malware Classification project in GCP after that.
>   Does GCP support huge data size - as dataset has compressed file of 17GB and after unzip it would take 200 GB of space
>   Are Google providing that much space to work on this project.
>   Please help and guide me to start with this project

Comment: I am able to set up the GCP environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try to follow this [documentation](https://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/latest/public_server.html#notebook-public-server)?. As per your data size, that would depend on your Vm's disk size.

Comment: able to setup the environment.